# HttpResponse error django generic template

Tags: django, listview, django-class-based-views

I am able to render class based view generic ListView template using parameter hard coded in views.py.

```
class ResourceSearchView(generic.ListView):
    model = creations
    context_object_name = 'reviews'
    template_name = 'reviews.html'
    query = 'theory'

    # def get(self, request):
    #     if request.GET.get('q'):
    #         query = request.GET.get('q')
    #         print(query)

    queryset = creations.objects.filter(narrative__contains=query).order_by('-post_date')
```

However, when parameter is sent via form by GET method (below),

```
class ResourceSearchView(generic.ListView):
    model = creations
    context_object_name = 'reviews'
    template_name = 'reviews.html'
    query = 'theory'

    def get(self, request):
        if request.GET.get('q'):
            query = request.GET.get('q')
            print(query)

    queryset = creations.objects.filter(narrative__contains=query).order_by('-post_date')
```

I receive this error

> The view creations.views.ResourceSearchView didn't return an
>   HttpResponse object. It returned None instead.

Note that the parameter name q and associated value is being retrieved successfully (confirmed using print(query)).

Comment: What's confusing you about the error? You've defined a get method with only half the functionality it needs; it gets a parameter, but then does nothing. Why are you defining `get` at all? What are you hoping to achieve?

Answer (score 1):

So with CBV in Django, you have to return some kind of valid response that the interpreter can use to perform an actual HTTP action. Your `GET` method isn't returning anything and that's what is making Django angry. You can render a template or redirect the user to a view that renders a template but you must do **something**. One common pattern in CBV is to do something like:

```
return super().get(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

...which continues up the chain of method calls that ultimately renders a template or otherwise processes the response. You could also call `render_to_response()` directly yourself or if you're moving on from that view, redirect the user to  `get_success_url` or similar.

Have a look here (http://ccbv.co.uk) for an easy-to-read layout of all the current Django CBVs and which methods / variables they support.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the responses. Here is one solution.

```
class ResourceSearchView(generic.ListView):
    model = creations
    context_object_name = 'reviews'
    template_name = 'reviews.html'

    def get_queryset(self):
        query = self.request.GET.get('q')
        queryset = creations.objects.filter(narrative__contains=query).order_by('-post_date')
        return queryset
```